# Parse JS SDK: include(COLUMN) not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm using Parse JS SDK with Ionic.  Everything is going smoothly.

But this problem is making me pulling my hair.

I have a class (Game), that have 2 array columns (gameAttendee,gameAbsentee).
Each column has an array of pointers to Users class (Parse default class).

I want to include the data behind those pointers.

Here's where it's funny...
When I try the REST API, the include works just fine:
[image: Using REST API in Rested]
However, when I try to use the JS SDK, it doesn't work:
[image: Using JS SDK in CodeRunner:Node (keys are hidden)]

Any idea why & how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

The include was actually working. the problem was in this line:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

I was receiving the data, but reading it incorrectly.

Comment: So how did you read it correctly? Because I'm having the same issue and I can't figure out why res.json(mydata) isn't returning the correctly included column data.

Comment: @JakeChapman When you receive the object, you can do this: `object.get("column")`.